# Acumatica: How to turn a Custom Field into a Cash Account Selector?

Tags: attributes, selector, acumatica

I want to turn a user field into a selector control for ANY cash account, but I cannot figure out. Looking a similar field attributes I want a code like:

```
[CashAccount(typeof(Location.vBranchID), typeof(Search<CashAccount.cashAccountID>)]
```

But I cannot get it to work.

What do I need change in the code?

Comment: Can you describe what you mean by "I cannot get it to work" ? What are the symptoms or the results? Can you post a complete customization project somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

In the field Atttribute I miss the CA.CashAccount:

```
[PXDBString(32)]
[PXUIField(DisplayName="POS Cash Account",Visibility = PXUIVisibility.SelectorVisible)]
[PXSelector(typeof(Search<CashAccount.cashAccountID>))]
```

Fix it and change to return the field ID by the Account:

```
[PXDBString(32)]
[PXUIField(DisplayName="POS Cash Account",Visibility = PXUIVisibility.SelectorVisible)]
[PXSelector(typeof(Search<CA.CashAccount.cashAccountCD>))]
```

Now the selector is working. Thank you!